# Appending to a list within a function that is called implicitly

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this code, the generate() function is called implicitly by another function.

The question is as follows, in the code below is there a way to ensure that when the generate() function is called for instance 4 times in this case, values of b is saved in list p without replacing the preceding element appended to it, currently only one value of b is appended to t.

```
    import random as rand 
    f = [1,2,3,4]
    k = rand.choice(f)
    h = rand.choice(f)


    def generate():

        global b # declare b as global

        t = []
        b = k + h
        t.append(b) #Append b to all so that
        print 'all:',t

        c = 4**2

        return c

generate()


def evaluate():

    fit = (generate() * b) # generate() is used here

    print "fit:", fit

    # Some other expressions using variable b
    p = []
    for i in range(4):
        p.append(b)
    print 'p:',p

    return fit

evaluate()


#output
all: [3]
fit: 48
p: [3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: You should really try to reduce your example down to a SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/). As it stands it is difficult to understand what the problem is, let alone what is causing the problem.

Comment: @Peter Gibson thanks I will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a scope problem. Read up on scoping in Python with the links below and consider this example:

```
>>> results = []
>>> i = [0]
>>> def test():
...     i[0] = random.randint(0, 100)
...     print i
...     results.append(i)
...
>>> test()
[20]
>>> test()
[99]
>>> test()
[18]
>>> results
[[18], [18], [18]]
```

Note that even though the value of `i[0]` changes for each call to `test()`, we are appending the same list `i` to `results` each time - so when an element in `i` changes, the changes are reflected throughout the `results` list.

Links:

[Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-17/python-scope-basics

**EDIT**

To fix the above problem, you need to make sure you're not overwriting the same list in each call to `test()`. You can do this by creating a new list each time, or by copying the list before modifying it

```
>>> import copy
>>> def test():
...     j = copy.copy(i)
...     j[0] = random.randint(0, 100)
...     print j
...     results.append(j)
...
>>> results = []
>>> test()
[75]
>>> test()
[13]
>>> test()
[17]
>>> results
[[75], [13], [17]]
```

You mention that you are dealing with nested lists, in which case you should use `copy.deepcopy` instead of `copy.copy`. Deep copy will make copies of all of the elements in the list as well as the list itself.

Comment: Thank you, I will read up on that from the articles you have put up. So given your example, there is not a way to have [[20], [99], [18]] or [20, 99, 18]?

Comment: @Nobi you just have to create a new list each time. I'll edit the answer to demonstrate

Comment: Thank you for your help and the informative articles too. Kindly vote the question.

Answer (score 1):

`t` would need to be global ...

of coarse it only has one element you initialize it as empty and then append one item to it ... also its only available within the generate function ....

its also very unclear what you are trying to accomplish with generate (typically it would return a new individual...)

you can fix it so that t gets all the b's like so ...

```
t = []
def generate():
    global b # declare b as global
    b = k + h
    t.append(b) #Append b to all so that
    print 'all:',t
    c = 4**2
    return c
```

although I suspect you have alot more problems than that

Comment: yes it returns the individual, but how can t then be initialized such that it retains the previous value appended to it. Thank you

Comment: Im not sure you understand what an individual is ... what is this trying to solve? what does a single individual solution look like? how big is your population? what about crossover and mutation?

Comment: Ok so in my codes, the generator function returns an individual (nested list of items), that is passed to the evaluator function. The evaluator computes the fitness values with attributes of the population generated and that is actually where the issue is because the evaluator needs to calculate fitness for all the individuals generated but it does for only one and assigns that for all the others.

Comment: generator is only returning a single value(that is then multiplied by the mysterious `b` value) ... which im pretty sure is not what an individual is ...

Comment: The generator returns a lists of routes as individual. These routes have attributes like length, speed etc. These attributes are then used in the evaluator function to compute the fitness values for the candidates that are implicitly generated by doing the operations (crossover and mutation) on the individual. But the issue is as I pointed out, the fitness expression in the evaluator function only calculates and uses only one fitness value, when it should do that a number of times.